# VFD: Regenerative overvoltage trip during deceleration or stop

Tags: vfd

I have a Mitsubishi VFD Model: FR-F720.
It shows the error E0u3, which means according to the manual: "If regenerative energy causes the inverter's internal main circuit DC voltage to reach or exceed the specified value, the protective circuit is activated to stop the inverter output. The circuit may also be activated by a surge voltage produced in the power supply system".

This error keeps showing even when there is no motor connected.

I have tried the possible solutions that the manual offers, but they don't seem to work. However, I think, if I certainly need a brake resistor, I am not sure how to place it.

Do you have any suggestion/alternative to this fault?

Thank you.

Manual: http://dl.mitsubishielectric.com/dl/fa/document/manual/inv/ib0600177eng/ib0600177engf.pdf

Technical data:

Input: 48.8A 3PH AC200-220V 50Hz
             3PH AC200-240V 60Hz

Output: 3PH AC200-240Vmax 0.5-400Hz

Comment: (1) Link to the user manual, man, in the question - not in the comments. (2) What supply voltage, single or three, what are the relevant parameters set to (e.g. factory defaults). (3) Can you read the inverter DC bus voltage? What is the reading? Again, all the info should be in the question.

Comment: To the OP: Be careful. The voltages, including the DC bus voltage in the VFD can be lethal. Be very careful in probing around and connecting things to the VFD. Make sure the DC bus is discharged before you do any wiring. It can remain high for a while even after you unplug the VFD.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no motor connected, the input voltage must be high or have repetitive voltage spikes that cause the DC bus capacitors to charge to a voltage exceeding the trip point. It is not likely that the trip point is adjustable, but there may be a setting to indicate if the VFD ic connected to 200-208 volts or 220-240 volts. Look at the manual for that.

If the input power is clean and proper, there could be a failure in the VFD causing this.

A transien voltage condition that frequently causes this type of problem is the ringing transient voltage caused by switching power-factor correction capacitors. The transient only lasts about 2 cycles of the power waveform and doesn't have peak a peak voltage higher than about 30% above the normal line voltage peak. However enough energy can be transferred to the VFD bus capacitors to cause a trip.

A dynamic braking resistor should be connected only according to instructions provided by the VFD manufacturer. An appropriate control circuit is required. Some manufactures have recommended using a dynamic braking resistor for problems of this kind caused by switching power factor correction capacitors. The resistor power rating must be sufficient considering the frequency of switching. It would be preferable to use a capacitor switching method that doesn't cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it's usually capacitors somewhere else in the system, such as the Power Factor Correction capacitors mentioned.